# Why url() give me no values when calling inside included template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

Here is the code:

```
#list.html
{% if intentions %}
    <table class="table">
        {% for i in intentions %}
            {% url 'intentions.views.show' i.id as iUrl %}
            <tr>
                <td width="20%">
                    <span class="label label-success">x prayers</span>
                </td>
                <td><h3><a href="{{ iUrl }}">{{ i }}</a></h3></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% else %}
    <p>
        No intentions are available.
    </p>
{% endif %}
```

If this code is inside `index.html` everything is ok. If I try to move this code to separate file `list.html` and include in `index.html` like:

```
    {% include "list.html" with intentions=entries %}
```

I have no values in url attribute of `<a>` tag. Could someone give me answer why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list.html template might be missing

```
{% load url from future %}
```

Because you are using the 'as' syntax, the url tag fails silently.